# Why Can't I do this in C++?

Tags: c++

Why the method getName() is wrong ?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>

class People
{
public:
    char* getName();
    void  setName(char* n);

private:
    char* name;
};

void People::setName(char* n)
{
    name = new char(strlen(n));
    strcpy(name,n);
}  

char* People::getName()
{
    return name;   
}
```

Comment: Do what? (filling up the space)

Comment: This question is incomplete. Post errors and consistent code samples.

Comment: I've formatted the question for you. Now you can see that `setName` method wasn't declared.

Comment: If you can't do something in c++ this mean that You have some bug or You have reach your limit ;-).

Comment: Why are you including the string header, if you are going to use char anyways. Use a string, will make your life much easier.

Comment: You should allocate space for the trailing null character, i.e. `name = new char(strlen(n)+1);` (that is, if you really want to use `char*` instead of `string`)

Comment: @Sven: not so much, because `new char(strlen(n)+1)` still only allocates a *single* char, whose initial value is the `size_t` value `strlen(n)+1`, converted to `char`.

Comment: So it should be name = new char[strlen(n)+1] ;

Comment: @Steve: right, missed the wrong parentheses.

Comment: @DumbCoder `#include <string.h>` == `#include <cstring>` != `#include <string>` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things here.  Firstly, as Ignacio pointed out (assuming this was your question in the first place, it's a bit vague), we have private members so that other classes can't arbitrarily screw with them.  We expose what we **want** other classes to use through a public interface.

Secondly, given that this is C++, I highly recommend you use `std::string` as opposed to `char*`.  Here's your class again:

```
#include <string>

class Person
{
private:
    std::string m_Name;

public:
    const std::string& getName() const {return(m_Name);};    
}; // eo class Person
```

What have we done here?

1) We've got a C++ `std::string` which handles all the business of strings for us.  We don't have to worry about memory-allocation, insufficient buffer sizes, etceteras.

2) It's private, nobody can screw with it, so external classes can't go:

```
Person p;
p.m_Name = "hahaha, I just messed with you";
```

3) To let users of our class get access to the name, we return a `const std::string&`.  They can use it, see it, but not modify it (unless, of course, they const_cast<> it away, but we've at least showed our intention).

4) The getter is marked as const.  This tells the compiler we won't be altering any members of the class during this call.

I hope this has answered whatever your question was.  I have no idea at this point.

Answer (score 7):

Because `Class` should be `class`.

Now with your edit, you don't declare `setName` in your class definition.

Compilers are picky (like us). Why don't you show us exactly what the compiler is telling you.

Answer (score 2):

Because you expose the underlying structure of private data in the object. Make a copy and return that.

Comment: I need to make a copy of the name in the getName method and then return that ?

Comment: Yes. It will be up to the caller to free the copy.

Comment: +1! That is not exactly an error, but he should do it anyway.

Comment: Returning a const reference is often OK too. But I'd rather use std::string

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly legal. What error are you encountering?

**PS** Class must be lowercase `c` as in `class`.

---

From your **edit** `setName()` is not defined in your `People` class definition.

Also,

```
name = new char(strlen(n));
```

Is erronous. You should either declare it like this:

```
name = new char[strlen(n)];
```

OR

```
name = new char[255]; //Constant value.
```

OR

```
name = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen*(n));
```

Comment: it works but I have read that the method getName() is wrong but I don't know why.

Comment: If it works, then it's not wrong...where did you get such info? Can you post the link of your source?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: `new char[x]` doesn't require a constant value. It can be any value calculated at runtime, just like `malloc(x)`.

Comment: @Steve, won't the compiler complain about the "constant term between brackets"?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: no, because in this context it's not specifying the static type of an array (which would require an integer constant expression). The type of the expression `new char[whatever]` is `char*`, regardless of the size specified.

Comment: See 5.3.4 in the standard. In particular the grammar definition of *direct-new-declarator* as "[expression]" optionally followed by any number of "[constant-expression]", and the example given in 5.3.4/6.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, thanks...updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you fix the `Class` typo : it should be `class` .

Provide compilation error log when you ask this type of question, we can't say anything useful but guess if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
```

Use string instead of char, after all you are including the string header.

```
using namespace std;
class People  
{  
public:  
    string getName();    
private:  
    string name;    
};
```

Returning a handle, char pointer, to private data, name , from getName is a [bad idea](http://gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm)

Comment: <iostream.h> is depreciated. Include <iostream> instead. Also <string.h> will most likely include the wrong header.

Comment: @VJo - I had mentioned it, just posted at the wrong time. And why the down vote ?

Comment: Downvoted because you're "using" the whole std namespace in what is probably a header. You're begging for a name clash.

Comment: @bltxd - It is wrong in practice. But for this small code snippet, I wouldn't mind using it. And the OP hasn't mentioned anything about any namespaces he maybe using. Doesn't seem to be a header also, when declaration and definition are in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Your buffer allocated is one byte smaller than the input string n. I think you forget the space for trailing '\0'.